# Sharing content on Facebook not displaying correctly

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, share

One of the problems I have is that my title contains an "&" but it displays as "&" when I click share.

Another problem I have is that the code below does not recognize "< br >" or "\n".

How do I make it so it will recognize "&, ', -, etc.." as well as line breaks.

```
<?php
$gettitle = get_the_title();
$getcontent = get_the_content();
$content = substr($getcontent, 0, 20);
$content .= "<br>".$moretexthere;
$link = get_permalink();

$title=urlencode($gettitle);
$url=urlencode($link);
$summary=urlencode($content);
?>

<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i use this as sharer url..

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODEDURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `urlencode` PHP function.

> "This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL..."

http://php.net/urlencode

**WordPress Example:**

```
<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>
```